# #Docusign, #Salesforce and Workflow

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

How do you fire Docusign in Salesforce using workflow or process builder. When a field (for example "send docusign") equals true, need a workflow that sends a docusign template to an email address on a custom object. Is there a formula I can use in Process Builder?

Comment: I'm after looking for the answer as well, please update if you able to figured out or find the answer.

Comment: I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861075/automate-to-initiate-docusign-documents